# automatic insert_into

Tags: sql

I have a view in my database where data is stored, it has 2 columns (ID and value) and 3 rows (ID1, 2 and 3), the ID never changes but the value column of this ID always has a new value (e.g. ID : 1 value : False; ID :2 value : 55), the ID1 always changes from True to False and ID2 and 3 always have new values
I have created a new table with 2 columns (ID and Value).
I want to write a program that every time the value of ( ID 1 ) changes from False to True in the view, a new row is automatically inserted in the new table with the value of ID2 and ID3).

this is my program :

```
SELECT dbo.View1.Value , View_1.Value , 
FROM dbo.View1 CROSS JOIN
                         dbo.View1 AS View1_1 
                     

WHERE (dbo.View1ID = 2)AND (View1_1.ID = 3)
```

it does what I want, but only when I run the program, I want this insert function to happen automatically every time the ID1 in the view changes from false to true. can you please help me

Comment: Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.  sQL Server and MySQL are completely different products.

Comment: Data is stored i base _tables_, not in views. A view is more or less a stored query, which is executed when you select from the view.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.